# How test in Java ee using Arquillian maven multiple project

Tags: java, maven, jboss-arquillian

I have an ejb project(maven) and i want run test case using Arquillian (jboss managed)  ,I had try two different ways one to create using ShrinkWrap war and load as library the pom file project and the other was  createFileFromZipfile the question is what can i do if maven have i multiple dependency with other modules ?

Comment: Can you be more specific of what the issue is?

Comment: Is this the same question as Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46516965/how-to-add-classes-from-another-to-the-arquillian-deployment-archive?