# How to add classes from another to the Arquillian deployment archive?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss-arquillian

I'm getting started with Arquillian and followed the tutorial. It covers how to inject EJBs into a test case. Since Arquillian is targeting Java Web and EE projects, I'm very suprised that the separation of entity classes and EJB interfaces wasn't covered in the tutorial since at least EE projects where everything is dumped in one project are rare.

Since there's no coverage in the tutorial and no understandable error message by any of the EE containers, I managed to extract a test case by trial and error which shows that classes used in

```
@Deployment
public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
    return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
        .addClasses(MyXBean.class, DefaultMyXBean.class, TermsOfUse.class)
        .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
}
```

which are on the classpath, but not in the same Maven project the test in contained in, fail due to `NoClassDefFoundError`. Moving the class into the project without touching anything else makes the deployment work.

Is there any way to use Arquillian in a "real" Java EE in which entities and interfaces are not contained into the `.war` of the test, but as a sibling inside the parent `.ear` archive of the `.war`?

I could think of adding JARs from the Maven cache with hardcoded pathes, but that can't be it, can it?

[How test in Java ee using Arquillian maven multiple project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663271/how-test-in-java-ee-using-arquillian-maven-multiple-project) might be about the same issue.

Comment: `EE projects where everything is dumped in one project are rare` why that? At least with jboss7 and  wildfly you do not need to use EARs anymore.

Comment: Maybe I missed the most recent Java EE development, but afaik EARs containing separate WAR and JAR archive(s) have their legitimate place in the world. Can they be handled well with Arquillian and how?

Answer (score 2):

An EAR deployment with libraries can be built like this:

```
@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createDeploymentPackage() throws IOException {
    MavenDependencyResolver resolver = DependencyResolvers  
         .use(MavenDependencyResolver.class)  
         .loadMetadataFromPom("test1-pom.xml");  

    final JavaArchive ejbJar = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "my-ejbs.jar").addClass(SomeEjb.class);

    final WebArchive webApp = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "my-webap.war").addClass(MyServlet.class);
    final EnterpriseArchive ear = ShrinkWrap.create(EnterpriseArchive.class)
            .setApplicationXML("application.xml")
            .addAsLibraries(resolver.artifact("log4j:log4j:1.2.17").resolveAsFiles()) 
            .addAsModule(ejbJar)
            .addAsModule(webApp);
    return ear;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. 1. Which version of Arquillian and Shrinkwrap is this refererring to? `MavenDependencyResolver` seems to be part of ShrinkWrap resolver 1.x. 2. This means that I have to manage the versions of dependencies at two locations, right? That would be extremely error prone and makes me doubt the usability of and hype around Arquillian.

Comment: To be honest it's been a while. I see that there is newer version with a different API at [ShrinkWrap Resolvers](https://github.com/shrinkwrap/resolver#resolution-of-artifacts-specified-by-maven-coordinates)